# ESLint: TopBarClass not found in './TopBar'(import/named)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building a React app using JSX & I'm getting the following error from ESLint:

**ESLint: TopBarClass not found in './TopBar'(import/named)**

Here's how the file looks that's producing the error.

```
import React from 'react';

import { TopBarClass } from './TopBar';

export default class Game extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { state } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="game-inner-container">
        { TopBarClass({ isMobileOrSmall: state.isMobileOrSmall }) }
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

However inside my `TopBar.js` I've got the following:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TopBarClass extends React.Component {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
import { TopBarClass } from './TopBar';
```

To

```
import TopBarClass from './TopBar';
```

You are using default export, so you should import it without `{` / `}`

Or you could change the `export default` to only `export`, then what is inside `{` / `}` should match the component's name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use import in correct way, like as below

```
import TopBarClass  from './TopBar';
```

It will work fine.